# grunt serve - returns -> org/jruby/RubyFile.java: No such process

Tags: windows-7, gruntjs, jruby, compass

I built a test project with `yo angular`. 
When I run `grunt serve -v`, using jruby 1.7.18 on Windows 7, compass fails with the following error

> ```
> Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task 
> [D] Task source: test\node_modules\grunt-concurrent\tasks\concurrent.js 
> Verifying property concurrent.server exists in config...OK 
> Files: [no src] -> server 
> Options: limit=2 
> Warning: Errno::ESRCH on line ["941"] of org/jruby/RubyFile.java: No such process - test/.tmp/styles/main.css
> ```

Diving into the grunt code, it seems that the problem is related to the way jruby instantiate the compass process on Windows 7, but I can't figure out exactly how is done...

If I run the same command using Windows 7+jruby 1.7.15 or OS X+jruby 1.7.18 everything goes fine.

My setup is:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Java SE (build 1.8.0_25-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
- jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551)
- npm 2.1.18
- grunt-cli v0.1.13
- grunt v0.4.5